# Can't add UIImageView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, uiimageview

I try to add Image into my view that in `UIScrollView`

**here is my .h**

```
@interface NormalDetail : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate> {   
    IBOutlet UIImageView *lineImg;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *lineImg;

@end
```

**and here is my .m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //Set ScrollView
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320.0f, 1800.0f); 
    //End Set ScrollView
    [self setupTextView];
}


- (void) setupTextView
{
    textDescription.scrollEnabled = NO;
    NSString *foo = @"Hello Test";
    textDescription.text = foo;
    /*Here is something for dynamic textview*/
    CGRect frame;
    frame = textDescription.frame;
    frame.size.height = [textDescription contentSize].height;
    textDescription.frame = frame;
     /**/

    int linePosition = frame.size.height+20;
    lineImg = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"line.png"]];
    CGRect line2Frame = CGRectMake(-8, 600, 328, 10);
    lineImg.frame = line2Frame;
}
```

What's wrong with my code , My pic didn't appear. help me please ;(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will needed to the UIImageView to the scorllView.

```
- (void) setupTextView
{
    textDescription.scrollEnabled = NO;
    NSString *foo = @"Hello Test";
    textDescription.text = foo;
    /*Here is something for dynamic textview*/
    CGRect frame;
    frame = textDescription.frame;
    frame.size.height = [textDescription contentSize].height;
    textDescription.frame = frame;
     /**/

    int linePosition = frame.size.height+20;
    lineImg = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"line.png"]];
    CGRect line2Frame = CGRectMake(-8, 600, 328, 10);
    lineImg.frame = line2Frame;

     //Add the image view as a subview to yout scrollview.
    [scrollView addSubView:lineImg];
}
```

Comment: And also use `IBOutlet` only when you have added the object in xib.
When you are using `IBOutlet` use it as

    ` IBOutlet Class *ObjectName;`
for declaration.

and create property as

    `@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet Class *ObjectName;`

and don't forget to bind the object with xib.

Comment: No, in this case it is not. The code does not use the . syntax for accessing the property.